# extjs showing hidden columns under 'Columns'

Tags: extjs

In extjs I have a GridPanel. The GridPanel has some hidden columns. Now when I click on the Grid menu, there is an option called 'Columns'. When you mouseover 'Columns'  you can check/uncheck the columns you want to show/hide.
Be default the hidden columns are also showing up on mouseover. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from column def reference:

hidden : Boolean

Optional. true to initially hide this column. Defaults to false. A hidden column may be shown via the header row menu. 
**If a column is never to be shown, simply do not include this column in the Column Model at all.**

Answer (score 7):

You can use such a property for your columns:

```
hideable:false
```

In this case these columns can not participate in showing/hiding.

Comment: This is the correct answer, for those reading.  Under the "columns:" section, you'd add the property "hideable" with a value of "false" to the column, if you do not want the end user to control whether this column is hidden or not in the list view.  The "hidden" attribute/property controls whether it is hidden or not.

Comment: correct answer - thanks :)

`hidden   : true,`
`hideable : false,`